# C++ sort vector using non-static member function

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a class called `Sorter`. It has two public items.

1. `int` type variable `choice`
2. member function called `compare` with a `int` type return value that accepts two objects as parameter.

I tried creating an instance of `Sorter` while passing `choice` with a value to the constructor,

Then i wanted to use C++ `sort` function to sort a `vector`. and to pass the member function `compare` of the instance i created.

The `compare` member function uses the variable `choice` to decide the sorting mechanism.

But i was not able to get the pointer to the member function `compare` of an instance of `Sorter`.

Could someone advice me on this?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. Please post some code, like the definition of `Sorter` and a usage example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the structure of your `Sorter` class, you could make it a function object by defining `operator ()` like this:

```
bool Sorter::operator ()(const MyObject &o1, const MyObject &o2) {
  // return true if o1 < o2
}
```

Then you can just pass an instance of your `Sorter` class to [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the standard library is a bit lacking in combinators for things like this. However, [boost::lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/lambda.html) can do the job:

```
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

namespace l = boost::lambda;

struct foo {
    bool bar(char, char);
};


void test(foo *pFoo) {
    char a[2] = {0};

    std::sort(a, a+1,
            l::bind(&foo::bar, pFoo, l::_1, l::_2));
}
```